# C++ ansi namespaces in object browser

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++11, objectbrowser

I'm wondering if it is possible to view what's "inside" the C++ ansi/iso namespaces just like visual basic or c# using the visual studio's object browser. Like view what functions are in the namespace "std", or what's in the iostream or cstring (are those namespaces?). I just started learning C++, so it would be very useful if I knew what built-in functions are at my disposal. Is it possible with the object browser or I'm looking in the wrong place?

Comment: what you mean with ansi/iso namespaces? that makes no sense.

Comment: I think the poster is asking about reflection / introspection.  41453 might be relevant here.